# ¿Obtener suma total de una columna de porcentajes SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs

Soy nuevo en SQL Server Reporting Services y realizando un reporte me encontré con un problema. Tengo una columna (`%Porcent`) en la cual por una formula custom en el reporte, obtengo los porcentajes de los valores totales (`TotalVal`) por año y necesito agregarle una `row` a la columna `%Porcent` que me entregue la suma total de los porcentajes, como la que tengo por todas las columnas por años.

La formula custom que tengo para obtener los porcentajes es:

```
Public Function ObtPorcentaje(ByVal Valor2019 As Double, ByVal Valor2018 As Double) As Double

Return (Valor2019-Valor2018)/Valor2018

End Function
```

La expresión que va en el `textbox` de la columna `%Porcent` es:

```
=Code.ObtPorcentaje(
Sum(IIF(Fields!anio.Value=2019,Fields!totalVal.Value,0)),
Sum(IIF(Fields!anio.Value=2018,Fields!totalVal.Value,0)))
```

Los valores que obtengo son:

```
          +---------------------+---------------------+
          |         2018        |         2019        |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|Nombre_R |Val1 |Val2 |TotalVal |Val1 |Val2 |TotalVal |%Porcent |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|R1       |4    |2    |6        |6    |2    |8        |33%      |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|R2       |4    |1    |5        |5    |3    |8        |60%      |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|Totales  |8    |3    |11       |11   |5    |16       |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Lo que espero obtener:

```
          +---------------------+---------------------+
          |         2018        |         2019        |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|Nombre_R |Val1 |Val2 |TotalVal |Val1 |Val2 |TotalVal |%Porcent |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|R1       |4    |2    |6        |6    |2    |8        |33%      |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|R2       |4    |1    |5        |5    |3    |8        |60%      |
+---------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+---------+---------+
|Totales  |8    |3    |11       |11   |5    |16       |93%      |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Intenté realizar una simple suma indicando el `textbox` con la formula `Sum`, es decir: `(=Sum(ReportItems!"nombre_del_textbox".Value)`, pero me da el error: `Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers`

Alguna ayuda?. Muchas Gracias.